# Carousel slider loads items vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, carousel, elementor

I am having an issue on my [website](https://staging-nccbwebsite.kinsta.cloud/connect-groups/)  I have added an item carousel (using Happy Addons for Elementor) to the dropdowns andwhen I load the page to view it, the title,caption and image load on the screen vertically then returns to being horizontal after about 5 seconds. This is happening every time.

Any pointers on how I can fix this or automatically load the horizontal carousel?

On load:

[image]

After 5+ seconds: (correct view)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It might be some global css rule that's affecting your carousel display property when the page in rendering.

Try forcing the display to inline-block to check if it's going to work, if so, then you can inspect the carousel to see where this property is being changed.

Comment: Would be cool if you can give a code example and it would be clear for the others to understand your point